# MySQL select rows until fixed number of condition is reached

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have this table

```
id  fruit
---------
1   apple
2   banana <--
3   apple
4   apple
5   apple
6   apple
7   banana <----

8   apple
9   banana
10  apple
```

And I want to select rows until 2 bananas are found, like

```
SELECT id FROM table_fruit UNTIL number_of_bananas = 2
```

So the result would be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

How could I achieve this?

**thanks**

I wish I could give credits to all of you who answered my question. I'v tested all of them, and they all work perfectly (got the expected result).

Though answers of Devart and ypercube seem a little bit complex and difficult for me to understand.

And since AnandPhadke was the first one provided a working solution, I'll choose his answer as accepted.

You guys are awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from tables where id <=

(
select id from (
select id from tables where fruit='banana'
order by id limit 2) a order by id desc limit 1
)
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e901/9)

Answer (score 3):

Try this query -

```
SELECT id, fruit FROM (
  SELECT
    b.*, @b:=IF(b.fruit = 'banana', 1, 0) + @b AS banana_number
  FROM
    bananas b,
  (SELECT @b := 0) t
  ORDER BY id) t2
WHERE
  banana_number < 2 OR banana_number = 2 AND fruit = 'banana'
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97565/3)

Answer (score 2):

[@Devart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13172562/1369235) is perfect but it's an alternative option to we can use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_fruit WHERE id <=
(
    SELECT id FROM 
    (SELECT id FROM table_fruit WHERE fruit='banana' ORDER BY id LIMIT 2) a
    ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
);
```

Or using `MAX`

```
SELECT * FROM table_fruit WHERE id <=
(
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM 
    (SELECT id FROM table_fruit WHERE fruit='banana' ORDER BY id LIMIT 2) a
);
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97565/17)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table_fruit where id <=
(
   select max(id) from
   (select id from table_fruit where fruit='banana' order by id limit 2) t
)
```

Comment: I think this query has better performance then mine. There should be `id` and `fruit` indexed. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

If there are less than 2 rows with `'banana'`, this will return all rows of the table:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table_fruit AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id
      FROM
        ( SELECT id
          FROM table_fruit
          WHERE fruit = 'banana'
          ORDER BY id
            LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
        ) AS lim2
    ) AS lim
    ON t.id <= lim.id
    OR lim.id IS NULL  ;
```